# List Comprehension Not Working Through All Elements

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I'm working on a scrabble solver. I have 81 squares, A1 (top left corner) to I9 (bottom left)
and 3 lists of lists of length 9 with 9 elements each for the rows, columns and sub grids respectively.

I also have a masterList = sub + col + row

For example:

```
row[0] = [['1A', '2A', '3A', '4A', '5A','6A','7A','8A','9A']]
```

When I do this:

```
test = [i for i in masterList if 'A1' in i]
print test
print len(test)
```

The length is only 2 (it should be 3) and it only prints from the first 2 lists that make up masterList (so in this instance, it does not find row[0].

```
 test2 = [i for i in row if 'A1' in i]
 print test2
```

Works correctly. I'm not sure why it is doing this.

Comment: Impossible. An assignment in `print` statement will produce syntax error.

Comment: My bad, accidentally failed copy paste somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first and second list comprehension are not identical:

```
test = [i for i in test if 'A1' in masterList]
```

is not the same as

```
 test2 = [i for i in row if 'A1' in i]
```

For one, the ONLY thing the first test checks is to see if 'A1' is in masterList, you're not actually iteratively checking anything.

I can't explain why/what you should be getting because it's not clear from your question what is contained in `test` initially, but the fact that you're checking to see `if 'A1' in i` in one list comp and `if 'A1' in masterList` in the other is probably the source of the discrepancy.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot place an assigment statement with a `print`. Separate them as follows:

```
test = [i for i in test if 'A1' in masterList]
print test
print len(test)
```

As you can see [**here**](http://repl.it/S40): `print a = ...` is invalid syntax

Comment: I messed up copy paste somehow, probably while spamming u and Ctrl R in between trying to figure out why this isn't working as expected. Can you help me now?